# Execute two function in single transaction with rollback

Tags: c#, oracle, c#-4.0, datagridview, oracle11gr2

Order Table with `Primary Key` **Order_id**

Order_details with `referential integrity` **Order_id** to the `Primary Key` in Order table

`F_INS_ORDER_DATA` oracle function will recive data from `DataGridView` and insert it into Oracle Database
the function consist of two insert statement

1. first one will insert one record into Order table and returning out the `primary key` **Order_id** assigned by trigger on table
2. second one will get the **Order_id** returned from first statement and use it as referential integrity
   in the order_details table to insert all items within the order (`DataGridView`) in it 
   and keep the **order_id** is same for all records  into Order_details table while it `primary key` at order table

**Note**
I am using that approach to force all transactions to be finished in one transaction so 
if any error accord in any step the `rollback` will `rollback` all changes done by the function
as nothing happen (One round trip transaction)

I guess solution maybe like below, but looking for better ways or improvements...

make two function `F_INS_ORDER_DATA` and `F_INS_ORDER_DETAILS_DATA`

but in that case how to keep all changes finished in **ONE SINGLE TRANSACTION**???

**C# Code**

```
            string connstr = @"Data Source=orcl; User Id=user; password=pwd;";
            string insertcmdtxt = @"F_INS_ORDER_DATA";   

            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(insertcmdtxt, conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.CommandText = insertcmdtxt;

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in DGV_INVOICE.Rows)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(":vORDER_ID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_CUSTOMER_ID", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value     = TB_CUSTOMER_ID.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_ORDER_NOTE", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value   = TB_ORDER_NOTE.Text;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_PRODUCT_ID", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value      = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_PRODUCT_ID"].Index].Value;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_UNIT_PRICE", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value      = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_UNIT_PRICE"].Index].Value;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_QUANTITY", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value        = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_QUANTITY"].Index].Value;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_DISCOUNT", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value        = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_DISCOUNT"].Index].Value;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_ORDER_STATUS", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = '1';
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_ITEM_NOTE", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value    = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_ITEM_NOTE"].Index].Value;

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        TB_INVOICE_ID.Text = (cmd.Parameters[":vORDER_ID"].Value).ToString();
                    }                        
                }
                catch (Exception EX)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(EX.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }
            }
```

**Oracle Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_INS_Order_Data (P_CUSTOMER_ID     IN NUMBER,
                                                                                       P_ORDER_NOTE       IN VARCHAR2,
                                                                                       P_PRODUCT_ID        IN NUMBER,
                                                                                       P_UNIT_PRICE         IN NUMBER,
                                                                                       P_QUANTITY           IN NUMBER,
                                                                                       P_DISCOUNT           IN NUMBER,
                                                                                       P_ORDER_STATUS  IN VARCHAR2,
                                                                                       P_ITEM_NOTE         IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   VOrder_Id      NUMBER;                --ORDER_ID Filled by trigger
   vCreated_by   VARCHAR2 (64)         := 'SYSTEM';
   vCreated_On   DATE                        := SYSDATE;

   sql_stmt           VARCHAR2 (4000);
   ERR_CODE      VARCHAR2(64);
   ERR_MSG       VARCHAR2(1024);

BEGIN

    SAVEPOINT Setp1;

    sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO orders (ORDER_ID,
                                                          CUSTOMER_ID,
                                                          NOTES,
                                                          CREATED_BY,
                                                          CREATED_ON)
                                            VALUES (NULL,                       --ORDER_ID Filled by trigger
                                                          :PCUSTOMER_ID,    --CUSTOMER_ID
                                                          :POrderNote,            --NOTES
                                                          :PCREATED_BY,       --CREATED_BY
                                                          :PCREATED_ON)     --CREATED_ON
                      RETURNING ORDER_ID INTO :vORDER_ID';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING P_CUSTOMER_ID,
                                                                   P_ORDER_NOTE,
                                                                   vCreated_by,
                                                                   vCreated_ON
                      RETURNING INTO vORDER_ID;

    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (sql_stmt);    /* For Testing Purpose */


    sql_stmt:='INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAILS (ORDER_ID,
                                                                           PRODUCT_ID,
                                                                           UNIT_PRICE,
                                                                           QUANTITY,
                                                                           DISCOUNT,
                                                                           ORDER_STATUS,
                                                                           NOTES,
                                                                           CREATED_BY,
                                                                           CREATED_ON)
                                                           VALUES ( :PvORDER_ID,              --ORDER_ID,
                                                                           :PPRODUCT_ID,          --PRODUCT_ID
                                                                           :PUNIT_PRICE,           --UNIT_PRICE
                                                                           :PQUANTITY,             --QUANTITY
                                                                           :PDISCOUNT,             --DISCOUNT
                                                                           :PORDER_STATUS,    --ORDER_STATUS
                                                                           :PItem_Note,                 --NOTES
                                                                           :PCREATED_BY,          --CREATED_BY
                                                                           :PCREATED_ON         --CREATED_ON
                                                                          )';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING vORDER_ID,
                                                                   P_PRODUCT_ID,
                                                                   P_UNIT_PRICE,
                                                                   P_QUANTITY,
                                                                   P_DISCOUNT,
                                                                   P_ORDER_STATUS,
                                                                   P_ITEM_NOTE,
                                                                   vCreated_by,
                                                                   vCreated_On;

   --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (sql_stmt);    /* For Testing Purpose */

   RETURN (VOrder_Id);

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 

    ROLLBACK TO Setp1;

    ERR_CODE := SQLCODE;
    ERR_MSG := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 1024);

    sql_stmt := F_INS_ERROR_LOG(SYSDATE,                        --P_ERROR_TIME,
                                                       vCreated_by,                    --P_USER_ID,
                                                       'F_INS_Order_Data',      --P_PROGRAM_UNIT,
                                                       NULL,                              --P_ERROR_LOCATION,
                                                       NULL,                             --P_KEY_DATA_DESC,
                                                       ERR_CODE,                    --P_ERROR_CODE,
                                                       ERR_MSG);                    --P_ERROR_MSG)';

RETURN -1;

END F_INS_Order_Data;
/
```

**Update separate function in to two functions**

**First Function F_INS_ORDER_DATA**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_INS_ORDER_DATA (P_CUSTOMER_ID     IN NUMBER,
                                             P_ORDER_NOTE       IN VARCHAR2,
                                             P_CREATED_BY         IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   vORDER_ID    NUMBER;
   vCreated_On   DATE:= SYSDATE;

   sql_stmt      VARCHAR2 (4000);
   ERR_CODE      VARCHAR2(64);
   ERR_MSG       VARCHAR2(1024);

BEGIN

    SAVEPOINT Setp1;

    sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO ORDERS (ORDER_ID,
                                     CUSTOMER_ID,
                                     NOTES,
                                     CREATED_BY,
                                     CREATED_ON)
                             VALUES (NULL,              --ORDER_ID Filled by trigger
                                     :PCUSTOMER_ID,     --CUSTOMER_ID
                                     :PORDER_NOTE,      --NOTES
                                     :PCREATED_BY,      --CREATED_BY
                                     :PCREATED_ON)      --CREATED_ON
                          RETURNING ORDER_ID INTO :vORDER_ID';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING P_CUSTOMER_ID,
                                     P_ORDER_NOTE,
                                     P_CREATED_BY,
                                     vCreated_ON
                      RETURNING INTO vORDER_ID;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (sql_stmt);    /* For Testing Purpose */

   RETURN (vOrder_Id);

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 

    ROLLBACK TO Setp1;

    ERR_CODE := SQLCODE;
    ERR_MSG := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 1024);

    sql_stmt := F_INS_ERROR_LOG(SYSDATE,         --P_ERROR_TIME,
                                P_CREATED_BY,                      --P_USER_ID,
                                'F_INS_ORDER_DATA',                --P_PROGRAM_UNIT,
                                'P_CUSTOMER_ID || vORDER_ID ',     --P_ERROR_LOCATION,
                                 P_CUSTOMER_ID||'/'||vORDER_ID,    --P_KEY_DATA_DESC,
                                 ERR_CODE,                         --P_ERROR_CODE,
                                 ERR_MSG);                         --P_ERROR_MSG)';

RETURN -1;

END F_INS_ORDER_DATA;
/
```

**Second Function F_INS_ORDER_DATA_DETAILS**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_INS_ORDER_DATA_DETAILS (P_ORDER_ID             IN NUMBER,
                                                     P_PRODUCT_ID        IN NUMBER,
                                                     P_UNIT_PRICE         IN NUMBER,
                                                     P_QUANTITY           IN NUMBER,
                                                     P_DISCOUNT           IN NUMBER,
                                                     P_ORDER_STATUS  IN VARCHAR2,
                                                     P_ITEM_NOTE         IN VARCHAR2,
                                                     P_CREATED_BY        IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   vCreated_On   DATE:= SYSDATE;

   sql_stmt           VARCHAR2 (4000);
   ERR_CODE      VARCHAR2(64);
   ERR_MSG       VARCHAR2(1024);

BEGIN

    SAVEPOINT Setp1;

    sql_stmt:='INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAILS (ORDER_ID,
                                          PRODUCT_ID,
                                          UNIT_PRICE,
                                          QUANTITY,
                                          DISCOUNT,
                                          ORDER_STATUS,
                                          NOTES,
                                          CREATED_BY,
                                          CREATED_ON)
                                  VALUES (:PvORDER_ID,         --ORDER_ID,
                                          :PPRODUCT_ID,        --PRODUCT_ID
                                          :PUNIT_PRICE,        --UNIT_PRICE
                                          :PQUANTITY,          --QUANTITY
                                          :PDISCOUNT,          --DISCOUNT
                                          :PORDER_STATUS,      --ORDER_STATUS
                                          :PItem_Note,         --NOTES
                                          :PCREATED_BY,        --CREATED_BY
                                          :PCREATED_ON         --CREATED_ON
                                          )';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING P_ORDER_ID,
                                     P_PRODUCT_ID,
                                     P_UNIT_PRICE,
                                     P_QUANTITY,
                                     P_DISCOUNT,
                                     P_ORDER_STATUS,
                                     P_ITEM_NOTE,
                                     P_CREATED_BY,
                                     vCreated_On;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (sql_stmt);    /* For Testing Purpose */

   RETURN (P_ORDER_ID);

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 

    ROLLBACK TO Setp1;

    ERR_CODE := SQLCODE;
    ERR_MSG := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 1024);

    sql_stmt := F_INS_ERROR_LOG(SYSDATE,                       --P_ERROR_TIME,
                                P_CREATED_BY,                  --P_USER_ID,
                                'F_INS_ORDER_DATA_DETAILS',    --P_PROGRAM_UNIT,
                                'P_ORDER_ID',                  --P_ERROR_LOCATION,
                                 P_ORDER_ID,                   --P_KEY_DATA_DESC,
                                 ERR_CODE,                     --P_ERROR_CODE,
                                 ERR_MSG);                     --P_ERROR_MSG)';

RETURN -1;

END F_INS_ORDER_DATA_DETAILS;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

1. unless you have explicit commit/rollback statement in your function then each call should happen in the one transaction.
2. since you are making multiple calls.. you will need to make sure `autocommit` is turned off for your connection. and do the commit manually
3. you don't need the `execute immediate` statements,.. you can just have the plain `INSERT` with the bind variables
4. since you call this function for each ORDER_DETAILS record.. first check to see if the parent ORDER record exists.. and insert it only if it does not.